# Unpacked union in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, unions, verification

```
typedef union {
      logic [1:0] c3; 
      bit [3:0] a3; 
      byte b3; 
  } pack3;

pack3 p3;
```

According to the LRM, the default initialization is according to the first member of the `union`, i.e., `logic` in the above example.  Therefore, `c3` assign to X and rest to assign to 0. But, when I compile in ModelSim and check in object window, then there is a different result for `a3` and `b3`.

Also when I assign `p3.a3 = 4'b0010;`, the value of `a3` and `b3` changes but not `c3`.  Please explain.  I know there is only memory available for each variable, so update in any value reflects all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no guarantees if you write to one member of an unpacked union and try to read another member (except for one special provision mentioned at the end of section *7.3 Unions* in the [1800-2012 LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)). You need to use a packed union if you want a guarantee in the layout of overlapping members.

Comment: thanks @dave_59 Yes, It works fine with the packed union but uncertainty without packed.